# Firebase Realtime Database doesn't update values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been writing an app using firebase database and for the last two days, it doesn't work.
What I mean by this is that I have a connection to the database, but when I try to read information by setting `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` it doesn't run the `ValueEventListener` even though I `updateChildren`.

```
        DatabaseReference mBlaze = FirebaseUtil.getDatabase(PLACES);
        mBlaze.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
        });
        long sTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (!triggers[0])
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - sTime > 5000)
```

I have a trigger value in the database used just to run the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`.

If I try to run this on my device\emulator, it won't print out the message "Hello", nor will it print out the message "Error".
The reason this is a problem is that I am trying to verify a code against the firebase database.
I give it a 5 second time window for the the value to change, meaning the code was found, and if after 5 second the value of `triggers[0]` doesn't change, it means the code isn't valid.

During my attempts to reduce the code I have stumble upon the `setLogLevel` which after I used it with `Level.DEBUG`, I have found that this line appears over and over again:

> Error fetching token: The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.

Comment: First of all, the `ValueEventListener` is supposed to run even without the call to `updateChildren`. Second of all, did you check if `onCancelled` was called?

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time understanding what behavior you're seeing vs what behavior you expect. Can you reduce the code to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the JSON (as text, no screenshot) as it is before you run the code?

Comment: @TheSunshinator The `onCancelled` doesn't get called.
@FrankvanPuffelen I reduced the code, but I doubt it will cause the same problem \ lack of connection to you. Note that I found an error that occurs during my attempts to reduce the code.

Comment: Actually, the `while` loop can prevent the `ValueEventListener` from being triggered. I had a similar problem where I had a `while(true) if(isTriggered) break;` which seemed to be to heavy or had way more priority on processor than the `ValueEventListener` so it was never triggered and my program froze. You should use `interface` for callbacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated later on, when I was trying to reduce the code, I found the `setLogLevel` method, which is used with `Level.DEBUG`, which I then used to discover the error:

> Error fetching token: The user's credential is no longer valid. The user must sign in again.

Which after some snooping around I discovered, that due to the Firebase-Auth mechanism, which grants a user a token for 24 hours, and then de-auth's it, causes the failure to reach the sever.
So the solution would be to implement either a  perma-login [permanent login] feature, or every time the user destroys the application or starts it from scratch, check if there is a user logged in using the `getCurrentUser()` method in `FirebaseAuth`, and if there is one, log out.

TL;DR:
Make sure you don't have a user signed in for more than 24 hours, and if you do, disconnect them and then reconnect them.